# What happens when triac terminals MT1/MT2 are switched?

Tags: triac

According all literature, terminals MT1/A1 and MT2/A2 must be connected to neutral and phase respectively. What happens if you reverse the wiring? House sockets here are randomly wired, so it's a practical problem.

Comment: It would be a good idea to have a load in there somewhere, otherwise the triac will only switch once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens if the triggering circuit is fed with the same mains voltage (normal case of application), so everything twists and works as expected.